# Save an ms access form record source query as a named query in the query list

Tags: ms-access

I build a form  and create a record source query, using the "..." in the properties > data > record source row of the form properties.

Now I want to convert the record source query to a "named" query, that is, one that appears in the query list that I can open, edit and save.

Is there a way to do this besides copying the SQL from the form query into a new query and pointing the form record source to the new query?

Comment: Just open `Record Source` again and use `Save As` in Query Builder.

Comment: That's sounds exactly right, because I know I've done this before. However, I don't see a "Save As" when I right click on the Query Builder header, only "Save".  (BTW MS Access 2016 / 365)

Comment: In Access 2013 it is the second button from right in the ribbon (Design View or SQL View)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Access 2016, to save a Record Source as a query, use the following steps:

1. Open up the record source in query view
2. Click file (top-right button)
3. Click Save As
4. Click Save Object As
5. Click Save As again (the button with the floppy disk that showed up after the last step)

Comment: Yep.  Looks like MS moved it between 2013 and 2016. Grazie!